# Highly specific factorial calculations in PHP

Tags: php, math, statistics, factorial

I have been working on a PHP page that calculates probabilities of different outcomes while randomly selecting a sample group from a larger group consisted of two types of people (`+` and `-`).

For example, it can calculate the probability of having 0 (or `n`) smokers in a group of `1000` people randomly chosen from across the United States, considering that `0.15` of Americans are smokers (`+`).

It works very well while working with populations below `10000` people, but when it comes to bigger populations of like `1000000`, it echoes `0` for all probabilities unless the precision (number of digits after `.`) is increased to like `3000`. Even in that case it takes forever.

The code works by calculating the probability of `0` positives, and doing some calculations on it to get the probability of `1` positive, and so on. This is while most of these probabilities are useless.

I have been thinking that if I can figure out a fast way of calculating almost the exact (`99.999%` or higher) value of very big factorials (like `1000000!`), there wouldn't be the need for starting from `0`, and the calculation could have been started from the place where it is needed, and with very low precision to reduce the time it takes.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form method="get">
        target population:
        <input type="text" name="tpop"><br><br>
        selected population:
        <input type="text" name="selected"><br><br>
        fraction of positives:
        <input type="text" name="fop"><br><br>
        output margin:
        <input type="text" name="margin"><br><br>
        precision:
        <input type="text" name="precision"><br><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
if (isset($_GET["precision"],$_GET["tpop"],$_GET["selected"],$_GET["fop"],$_GET["margin"])&&$_GET["precision"]!=''&&$_GET["tpop"]!=''&&$_GET["selected"]!=''&&$_GET["fop"]!=''&&$_GET["margin"]!=''&&$_GET["tpop"]>=$_GET["selected"]&&$_GET["fop"]>=0&&$_GET["fop"]<=1){
    $tpop=$_GET["tpop"];
    $selected=$_GET["selected"];
    $fop=$_GET["fop"];
    $margin=$_GET["margin"];
    $ioioio=0;
    $precision=$_GET["precision"];

    $minor=($selected*$fop)-$margin;
    $maxor=$minor+(2*$margin);
    $popopo=bcmul($tpop,$fop);
    echo '<br><br>min is'.$minor.'max is'.$maxor.'<br><br>';

    $mmm=bcsub($tpop,$selected,$precision);
    $rea=bcsub($mmm,1,$precision);
    $fops=bcmul($tpop,$fop);
    $trss=bcsub($tpop,$fops,$precision);
    $trss=bcsub($trss,$selected,$precision);
    $trss=bcadd($trss,1,$precision);
    while($rea>=$trss){
    $mmm=bcmul($mmm,$rea,$precision);
    $rea=bcsub($rea,1,$precision);
}

$nnn=$tpop;
$sfg=bcsub($nnn,1,$precision);
$ugt=bcmul($tpop,$fop,$precision);
$uyt=bcsub($tpop,$ugt);
$uyt=bcadd($uyt,1,$precision);
while($sfg>=$uyt){
    $nnn=bcmul($nnn,$sfg,$precision); 
    $sfg=bcsub($sfg,1,$precision);
}

$zero=bcdiv($mmm,$nnn,$precision);

echo '0==>'.$zero.'<br><br>';
$a=$selected;
$b=($tpop-($tpop*$fop)-$selected+1);
$c=1;
$d=($tpop*$fop);
$i=1;

$origzero=$zero;
$save=$zero;

while($i<=$selected){

    if($d<=0){
        echo $i.'==>impossible<br><br>';
        $a--;
        $b++;
        $c++;
        $d--;
        $i++;
    }else{
        $zero=bcmul($zero,$a,$precision);
        $zero=bcmul($zero,$d,$precision);
        $zero=bcdiv($zero,$b,$precision);
        $zero=bcdiv($zero,$c,$precision);
        if($i>=$minor){
            if($i<=$maxor){
                if($i<=$popopo){
                    $ioioio=bcadd($ioioio,$zero,$precision);
                    echo 'following value is included in p value<br>';
                    echo $i.'==>'.$zero.'<br><br>';
                }
            }
        }
        $save=bcadd($save,$zero,$precision);

        $a--;
        $b++;
        $c++;
        $d--;
        $i++;
    }
}
echo 'precision==> '.$save.'<br><br>';
$savee = bcsub(1,$save,$precision);
echo '1-precision==> '.$savee.'<br><br>';
if($minor<0||$maxor>$selected){
    echo 'p value==>margin larger than surronding probabilties select an smaller margin to calculate p value';
} elseif($minor>0){
    echo 'p value==>'.$ioioio;
} else{
    $ioioiop=bcadd($ioioio,$origzero,$precision);
    echo 'p value(0included)==> '.$ioioiop;}
}
?>
```

dear @shukshin.ivan
many thanks for your response that was exactly what i was looking for : ]
this is an example of how it works for anyone else how might have the same question:

```
$x=950000;
$x =2*$x+1;
$P=pi();
$x =(log(2.0*$P)+log($x/2.0)*$x-$x-(1.0-7.0/(30.0*$x*$x))/(6.0*$x))/2.0;
$x=$x/log(10);
$ex=floor($x);              
$x=pow(10,$x-$ex);
$res=$x.'A';
$res=substr($x,0,6).'E'.$ex;
echo $res;
```

Comment: Can we have some formatting for the code, please?

Comment: Permutations and combinations are best calculated using the lngamma function rather than factorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Stirlings approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Versions_suitable_for_calculators). It is rather precise on large numbers. The meaning is that factorial can be calculated as an approximate

[image]

A set of other algorithms [can be found here](http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/FastFactorialFunctions.htm).